# run a code in java for only 60 seconds

Tags: java, delayed-execution

i need to run the following code for only 60 seconds

the code works prefect with delay for 2 sec and repeat every 5 seconds..

but here i need to do this all for 60 seconds only

```
        int delay = 3000; // delay for 3 sec. 
        int period = 5000; // repeat every 5 sec. 
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Would it run?"+System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }, delay, period);
```

Please let me know how to do this?

Comment: so the thread should sleep after 60 seconds or it should be dead ?? in either case , just create a check for 60 secs and kill it

Comment: i mean if you ned the thread to run every hour or so , then make it sleep , or if you need it just once , just kill it after 60 secs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it simply with [a `ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

- Schedule the task
- retrieve the `ScheduledFuture`
- cancel that future after 60 seconds:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Would it run?"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
};
final ScheduledFuture<?> handle =
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 2, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { handle.cancel(true); }
}, 60, SECONDS);
```

Comment: @assylias i need to kill how to do that

Comment: You need to make sure your task responds to interruptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class test{
static int delay = 3000; // delay for 3 sec. 
       static int period = 5000; // repeat every 5 sec. 
        static int totaltime = 0;   
public static void main(String ar[]){


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                test.totaltime+= ((test.delay+test.period)/1000);

                if(test.totaltime > 60)System.exit(0);
                System.out.println("Would it run?"+System.currentTimeMillis());

            }
        }, test.delay, test.period);
}
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this will work... I think the OP wants that Task to run for 60 seconds and then stop... Your code will start after a 60 seconds delay...

Comment: Yep, I agree, this version is much better. +1 :) .

Comment: then you have to calculate the time requiered for other statements and subtract it, i dont think its feasible

Answer (score 1):

You need to count how many times you've bee doing that, and then cancel:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Waiting {
    public static int times;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int delay = 3000;  // delay for 3 sec. 
        int period = 5000; // repeat every 5 sec. 
        times = 60000 / ( delay + period );


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                System.out.println( "Times remaining: " + Waiting.times );

                --Waiting.times;
                if ( Waiting.times == 0 ) {
                    this.cancel();
                    System.exit( 0 );
                }
            }
        }, delay, period); 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will times not need to be public static. I'm rusty in java but I don't think that that will be in scop.e

Comment: inside run() to use times variable means then final int times = 60000 so --times cannot assign final value

Comment: Yep. I was just being schematic.

Comment: @Baltasarq here how you decreament the times variable

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a timer that will go to 60 and set up an if something like this:

```
int time = 3;

 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
     if(time<60){
                System.out.println("Would it run?"+System.currentTimeMillis());
                time = time + 5;
     }
     else{ timer.stop(); }
            }
        }, delay, period);
```

Comment: variable `time` is not accessible inside innerclass

Answer (score 0):

Just call `cancel` from the `run` method after the desired number of repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest i never used timer, but if you want to run your task for some period of time, why dont use[`public void schedule(TimerTask task,long delay,                   long period)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

if i undarstand correctly, you want to run your task now, for 60secs, so:

`timer.schedule(myTask,0,60000);`

should do for you, but as i said, i never work with timers, so i'm not 100% sure will it work